# Apache: "Additionally, a 404 error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument" when file exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here's my .htaccess in /var/www/avatars (I can confirm this .htaccess is being read and executed);

```
ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/avatars/default.jpg
```

Here is what I get with a 404 page:

```
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Here is default.jpg:

https://coinchat.org:8001/avatars/default.jpg

Why is this error happening? It was working a day ago

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /default.jpg
```

If not, did you make any other changes to `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` or anything?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which format works? The one you posted or the one I posted?